# Android/Java - Best way to retrieve information from server?

Tags: java, android, networking, server

I have a server that stores a plain text file with a numerical value. The text file is constantly edited by the server every few minutes or so. What is the best way for an Android Client to retrieve the text file's contents?

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you running into? We won't write code for you.

Comment: I was thinking of using a BufferedReader and InputSteamReader to download the file into a string. I just want to know if there is a more efficient way or something.

Comment: It depends on how you can communicate with your server. I suggest to develop a kind of API that retrieve data from server so then you use http requests to get that.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way would be using Volley library with a string request.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.domain.com/file.txt");
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```